# Get Parameters from SSRS Report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I am trying to pull the parameters from an ssrs report. I have the following code.

```
var server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[WebConfigKeys.SSRSServer];

var protocol = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[WebConfigKeys.SSRSProtocol];

var serverReport = new ServerReport
{
    ReportPath = $"{protocol}://{server}/ReportServer?/Reports/{report.ReportName}"
};

var parameters = serverReport.GetParameters();
```

once the app tries to do the serverReport.GetParameters() call it is generating the below error:

> "The path of the item 'http://localhost/ReportServer?/Reports/PatientCareIncomplete/' is
>   not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other
>   restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path
>   must start with slash."

What am I missing that needs to be there or what is causing this issue?

Comment: @DavidG That's correct for a URL to an SSRS report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you set the `ReportServerUrl` property to the root folder of your report server and set the `ReportPath` to the path relative to the root:

```
var serverReport = new ServerReport
{
    ReportServerUrl = $"{protocol}://{server}/ReportServer";
    ReportPath = $"/Reports/{report.ReportName}";
};
```

Comment: Bulls-eye.  I was just trying this when I checked back to see if anyone had responded.  Thanks!